# How can I reverse a list?

Tags: recursion, scheme, reverse

What is the function to reverse a list in Scheme?

It needs to be able to handle nested lists. So that if you do something like `(reverse '(a (b c d) e))` you'll get `(e (b c d) a)` as the output.

How should I approach this problem? I'm not just looking for an answer, but something that will help me learn.

Comment: Better answer: (define (rev1 lst) (foldl cons '() lst))

Comment: Ordinarily, when I see "_it needs to be able to handle nested lists_", that would mean that `(reverse '(a (b c d) e))` --> `(e (d c b) a)`, i.e., the nested lists are _also_ reversed. What do you expect for `(reverse '(a (b c (d e))))`? I would expect `(((e d) c b) a)`, but the example suggests that the result should be `((b c (d e)) a)`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use:

```
(define (reverse1 l)
  (if (null? l)
     nil
     (append (reverse1 (cdr l)) (list (car l)))
  )
)
```

Explanation:

Rules:

1. If the list is empty, then the reverse list is also empty
2. Else behind the reverse tail of the list, add the first element of the list

Look at this code this way:

`reverse1` is name of the function and l is a parameter. If the list is empty then the reverse is also empty.
Else call the `reverse1` function with (cdr l) which is the tail of the list and append that to the first alement (car l) that you make as a list.

In your example (pseudocode):

```
1st iteration
l=>(a (bcd)e)
car l => a
cdr l => (bcd)e
list(car l) =>(a)
------------------
reverse( cdr l)"+"(a)
------------------
2nd iteration
l=>((bcd)e)
car l => (bcd)
cdr l =>e
list(car l)=>(bcd)
--------------------
reverse(cdr l)"+"((bcd))+(a)
-----------------------
3rd iteration
l=>e
car l=> e
cdr l => nil
list (car l) =>(e)
-------------------------
(e (bcd)a)
```

Comment: Note that this answer is written in Common Lisp, which uses `nil` instead of `'()`.

Comment: @erjiang that's not really true - while Common Lisp uses `nil` and Scheme doesn't, the function defined at the top of this answer is really Scheme, not Common Lisp. You would need to do something like `(define nil '())` in order for it to work though.

Comment: This works for me perfectly with just one minor edit (return items instead of nil):
(define (rev items)
    (if (null? items)
        items
        (append (rev (cdr items)) (list (car items)))
        )
    )
I run this in Petite Chez (http://www.scheme.com/)

Comment: Also there is built-in (reverse) procedure that returns the same result.

Comment: To avoid the nil/empty list issue, since you already know that l is empty from (null? l),that case could just return l. That will work regardless of exactly what null? checks for.

Comment: Be aware that this implementation may have performance problems. Take a look at this to see a better performant version of list reversing implementation: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/310/pwfong/Lisp/2/tutorial2.html

Answer (score 24):

```
(define (my-reverse ls)
  (define (my-reverse-2 ls acc)
    (if (null? ls)
      acc
      (my-reverse-2 (cdr ls) (cons (car ls) acc))))
  (my-reverse-2 ls '()))
```

This uses an accumulator variable to reverse the list, taking the first element off the incoming list and consing it to the front of the accumulator.  It hides the accumulator taking function and just exposes the function that takes a list, so the caller doesn't have to pass in the empty list.  That's why I have my-reverse-2.

```
(my-reverse-2 '(a (b c d) e) '()); will call
(my-reverse-2 '((b c d) e)  '(a)); which will call
(my-reverse-2 '(e)  '((b c d) a)); which will call
(my-reverse-2 '() '(e (b c d) a)); which will return
'(e (b c d) a)
```

Because the last function call in `my-reverse-2` is a call to `my-reverse-2`, and the return value is passed right through (the return value of the first call *is* the return value of the second call, and so on) `my-reverse-2` is *tail optimized*, which means it will not run out of room on the stack.  So it is safe to call this with a list as long as you like.

If you want it to apply to nested lists use something like this:

```
(define (deep-reverse ls)
  (define (deep-reverse-2 ls acc)
    (if (null? ls)
        acc
        (if (list? (car ls))
            (deep-reverse-2 (cdr ls) (cons (deep-reverse (car ls)) acc))
            (deep-reverse-2 (cdr ls) (cons (car ls) acc)))))
  (deep-reverse-2 ls '()))
```

This checks to see if the element is a list before adding it to the list, and if it is, reverses it first.
Since it calls itself to revers the inner list, it can handle arbitrary nesting.

`(deep-reverse '(a (b c d) e))` -> `'(e (d c b) a)`  which is in reverse alphabetical order, despite the fact that there is a nested list.
It evaluates as so:

```
(deep-reverse-2 '(a (b c d) e) '()); Which calls
(deep-reverse-2 '((b c d) e)  '(a))
(deep-reverse-2 '(e) (cons (deep-reverse-2 '(b c d) '()) '(a)))
(deep-reverse-2 '(e) (cons (deep-reverse-2 '(c d)  '(b)) '(a)))
(deep-reverse-2 '(e) (cons (deep-reverse-2 '(d)  '(c b)) '(a)))
(deep-reverse-2 '(e) (cons '(d c b) '(a)))
(deep-reverse-2 '(e)  '((d c b) a))
(deep-reverse-2 '() '(e (d c b) a))
'(e (d c b) a)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way that you can make a reverse function that applies to nested lists:

```
(define (reverse-deep l)
  (map (lambda (x) (if (list? x) (reverse-deep x) x)) (reverse l)))
```

Explanation in pseudo-code: 
Start by reversing the list as you would normally do
Then for each element in the reversed list:
- If the element is a list itself: Apply the procedure recursively
- Else: Don't touch the element

Answer (score 2):

This is a reverse function in [Racket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_(programming_language)) which I like much better than Scheme.

It uses the match pattern matching function only.

```
(define/match (rev l)
    [('()) '()]
    [((list a ... b)) (cons b (rev a))])

> (rev '(a (b c d) e))
'(e (b c d) a)
```

Comment: This uses O(n^2) time and O(n^2) space. Thus the longer the list gets the less likely you are ever going to get an answer before your patience go out or your memory runs out.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply reverse the elements in a list using foldr:

```
(foldr (lambda (a r) (append r (list a))) empty lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used code similar to [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

```
(define deep-rev-list
  (lambda (l)
     (cond ((null? l) (quote ()))
           ((atom? (car l))
             (swap-till-end (carl) (deep-rev-list (cdr l))))
           (else
             (swap-till-end (deep-rev-list (car l)) (deep-rev-list (cdr l)))))))


(define swap-till-end
   (lambda (elm lst)
      (cond ((null? lst) (cons elm '()))
            (else
               (cons (car lst) (swap-till-end elm (cdr lst)))))))

(define atom?
  (lambda (x)
    (and (not (null? x)) (not (pair? x)))))
```

I am reproducing it from memory. There may be some errors. I will correct the code if that's the case. But the technique used is similar to the commandments for nested lists given in THe Little Schemer :).  I checked it in DrRacket.

(deep-rev-list '((1 2) (3) ((4 5)))) returns (((5 4)) (3) (2 1))

Comment: What is "THe Little Schemer" and "DrRacket"? A book and an online tool, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
(define (rvrs ls)
  (if (null? ls)
    empty
    (append (rvrs (cdr ls)) (cons (car ls) empty))))
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea? How is it different from previous answers?