# Trying to reverse a list in Scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, reverse

Be forewarned: this is a homework problem. I'm trying to write a Scheme function that reverses a list. '(1 2 3) becomes '(3 2 1), etc. I'm not allowed to use the predefined function that does this.

Am I on the right track with what I wrote here?

```
;myReverse
(define (myReverse list)
    (if (null? list) '()
        (append (myReverse(cdr list)) car list)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reverse function in Scheme? \[Q: Reverse Nested List\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092113/what-is-the-reverse-function-in-scheme-q-reverse-nested-list)

Comment: the accepted answer in that thread is terrible (smells like O(N^2)), not in Scheme, and definitely not idiomatic. I'll put the right answer somewhere over there to avoid spoiling Ben's homework.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using `list` as an name is going to be odd, since Scheme is a Lisp-1. Call it `lst` instead.

Think about what you can do with `foldl`, `cons`, `'()`, and `lst`.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I on the right track with what I wrote here?

Yes. Some things to consider:

- `list` is a built-in function name, and one you might actually want to use in this solution, so you probably shouldn't name your formal that
- You forgot the parentheses around `car list`
- `append` expects two lists; you're passing it a list and a number

  ```
  > (append '(1) 2)
  (1 . 2)
  > (append '(1) '(2))
  (1 2)
  ```