# Scheme function to reverse a list

Tags: list, scheme, reverse

For my programming languages class I'm supposed to write a function in Scheme to reverse a list without using the pre-made reverse function.  So far what I got was

```
(define (reverseList lst)
(COND
((NULL? lst) '())
(ELSE (CONS (reverseList(CDR lst)) (CAR lst)))
))
```

The problem I'm having is that if I input a list, lets say `(a b c)` it gives me `(((() . c) . b) . a)`.

How am I supposed to get a clean list without multiple sets of parenthesis and the `.`'s?

Comment: Do you understand what each `.` means and why you're seeing so many parentheses?  The answers here will point you to a correct solution, and WillNess's solution covers what you're seeing, but you might also benefit from [Dot notation in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/1281433), and [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433).  You might also find [How to Reverse a List?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4092113/1281433) useful.

Comment: change the algorithm. Your algorithm is inserting an empty list in the head of the reversed list. and it keep doing this for the partial reversed. I think you mean to concatenate the lists so you get a flat list as a result intead of a list of list of list ... of list. use append instead of cons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that `cons` isn't receiving a *list* as its second parameter, so the answer you're building isn't a proper list, remember: a proper list is constructed by `cons`ing an element with a list, and the last list is empty.

One possible workaround for this is to use a helper function that builds the answer in an accumulator parameter, `cons`ing the elements in reverse - incidentally, this solution is tail recursive:

```
(define (reverse lst)
  (reverse-helper lst '()))

(define (reverse-helper lst acc)
  (if (null? lst)
      acc
      (reverse-helper (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc))))

(reverse '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: A better name for `reverse-helper` is [`append-reverse`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#append-reverse), since that's what that function is called in SRFI 1, and it looks less like an artificial helper and more like a real function. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are half way there. The order of the elements in your result is correct, only the structure needs fixing.

What you want is to perform this transformation:

```
 (((() . c) . b) . a)           ; input
 --------------------
 (((() . c) . b) . a)   ()      ; trans-
  ((() . c) . b)       (a)      ;      for-
   (() . c)          (b a)      ;         mation
    ()             (c b a)      ;               steps
      --------------------
                   (c b a)      ;               result
```

This is easy to code. The `car` and `cdr` of the interim value are immediately available to us. At each step, the next interim-result is constructed by `(cons (cdr interim-value) interim-result)`, and `interim-result` starts up as an empty list, because this is what we construct here - a *list*:

```
(define (transform-rev input)
   (let step  ( (interim-value    input)       ; initial set-up of 
                (interim-result    '() ) )     ;  the two loop variables
     (if (null? interim-value)
       interim-result                  ; return it in the end, or else
       (step  (car interim-value)      ; go on with the next interim value
              (cons                    ;      and the next interim result
                  (... what goes here? ...)
                  interim-result )))))
```

`interim-result` serves as an accumulator. This is what's known as "accumulator technique". `step` represents a loop's step coded with "named-let" syntax.

So overall reverse is

```
(define (my-reverse lst)
   (transform-rev 
       (reverseList lst)))
```

Can you tweak `transform-rev` so that it is able to accept the original list as an input, and thus skip the `reverseList` call? You only need to change the data-access parts, i.e. how you get the next interim value, and what you add into the interim result.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (my-reverse L)
 (fold cons '() L)) ;;left fold
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer? This was flagged as low-quality.

Comment: @CodeMaverick A fold starts out with an initial value (`'()` in this case), then updates that value with the given function (`cons` in this case) for each item in the list (from left-to-right in the case of a left fold). Since `cons` builds lists right-to-left, and since the input elements come from the incoming list left-to-right (due to the left fold), the resulting list is a reverse of the original. Similarly, you can copy a list by using a right-fold instead, which gets input elements from right-to-left.

Comment: Fold /fold-left is tail recursive as well, no stack overflows no matter how big the input list.

Answer (score 1):

Step through the list and keep appending the car of the list to the recursive call.

```
(define (reverseList lst)
(COND
((NULL? lst) '())
(ELSE (APPEND (reverseList(CDR lst)) (LIST (CAR      lst))))
))
```

Comment: Using `append` to build a list is kinda frowned upon, it means you're not recurring the right way. Besides it's terrible inefficient, think of it as [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_painter%27s_Algorithm#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm). Most of the time you want to use `cons` and tail recursion to build a list, see my answer.

Comment: That was a very interesting read. I guess I am one of the many graduates coming through with basic flaws :-) Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason or benefit to the helper function? It looks to me like you could just throw its code into the original function, [replacing acc with '()] and it would all work fine?

Comment: I wrote it as a helper because the original function receives only one parameter, but we needed two parameters for implementing the tail recursion. Normally I'd have written it as a named `let`, to avoid creating _two_ functions, but that might be harder to understand for the OP

Comment: in lisp append is not inefficient, you are not moving data, just setting pointers. Care not what Oscar Lopez says. the algorithm is ok, so it's ok.

Comment: tail recursion reason is for the compiler optimizer to turn a recursive function into an iterative function, after compiled you no longer has a function calling a function, what you get is a loop inside the function. Compilers cannot achieve this if the recursive function performs some operation upon return. A tail recursive function performs no operation upon return of a recursive call, so it can just return. The kind of function can be unrolled into a loop. You write a recursive solution, the compiler changes it to an iterative solution.

Comment: (define (reverse lst)
        (define (iter lst acc)
            (cond ((null? lst) acc)
                   (else (iter (cdr lst)
                         (cons (car lst) acc)))))
        (iter lst '()))

Comment: As you can see all operations are performed on call, none on return. At any given moment you have the result of the operation in acc. This design allows for the inner function to be changed into a loop. And bye bye recursion, bye bye stack frame creation, bye bye stack overflow.

Comment: the inner function parameters becomes local variables, the recursion call becomes modifiers of the locals { (iter (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc) => (set! lst (cdr lst)) (set! acc (cons (car lst) acc))) }, and the function body becomes a loop. :-)

Comment: @Alfgaar -- "_in lisp append is not inefficient, you are not moving data, just setting pointers_" is incorrect. In both Common Lisp and Scheme the entire structure of all lists to be appended is copied, except for the last object in the call to `append`, making `append` a linear time operation. Using `append` in a recursive call like this makes `reverseList` a quadratic time operation instead of the linear time operation that it should be. There are good uses for `append`, but this is not one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `cons`, try `append`

```
(define (reverseList lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (append (reverseList (cdr lst)) (list (car lst)) )
    )
)
```

a sample run would be:

```
1]=> (reverseList '(a b c 1 2 + -))

>>> (- + 2 1 c b a)
```

`car` will give you just one symbol but `cdr` a list

Always make sure that you provide `append` with two lists.

If you don't give two lists to the `cons` it will give you dotted pair `(a . b)` rather than a list.

See [Pairs and Lists](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pairs.html) for more information.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add anything since there is already another answer with almost identical code. Additionally, using `append` in recursive calls like this is usually a bad idea because `append` by itself is already a linear time operation. This implementation of `reverseList` has quadratic time complexity, and this becomes a real problem for large lists. But it can have (and should have) linear time complexity, e.g., by using an accumulator and consing on to it as in some of the other answers.