# Scheme reverse a list

Tags: recursion, lambda, scheme, racket, reverse

I am trying to reverse a list in Scheme using DrRacket.

Code:

```
(define rev
  (lambda(l)
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (append (rev (cdr l)) (list (car l))))))
```

If I input `(rev '(a((b)(c d)(((e))))))`, the output is `(((b) (c d) (((e)))) a)`.

I want it to be `(((((e)))(d c)(b))a)`. I looked here: [How to Reverse a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092113/how-to-reverse-a-list) but I get an even worse output. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trickier than it looks, you're trying to do a "deep reverse" on a list of lists, not only the elements are reversed, but also the structure … here, try this:

```
(define (rev l)
  (let loop ((lst l)
             (acc '()))
    (cond ((null? lst) acc)
          ((not (pair? lst)) lst)
          (else (loop (cdr lst) 
                      (cons (rev (car lst))
                            acc))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(rev '(a ((b) (c d) (((e))))))
=> '(((((e))) (d c) (b)) a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Never knew about the `let`, `loop`, and `acc` commands. **EDIT**: Would you happen to the know the equivalents of those commands using `lambda`? Professor might not let me use `loop` or `acc`. If not, that's fine.

Comment: Never mind! I looked up how let works and it makes much more sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This code will do it:

```
(define (rev-list lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      null
      (if (list? lst)
          (append (rev-list (cdr lst)
                  (list (rev-list (car lst))))
          lst)))
```

And the result is:

```
>>> (display (rev-list '((1 7) 5 (2 4 (5 9))) ))
(((9 5) 4 2) 5 (7 1))
```

The idea is simple: Return the `arg` if it's not a list, return `rev-list(arg)` otherwise.

Comment: the idea is simple but also naive. `append` is an expensive operation that can be easily avoided using preferred techniques

Comment: @Thankyou -- `append` is expensive, and this solution is a naive one, but that does not mean that it is not useful for an answer to show a different (even if inefficient or non-idiomatic) approach from the other solution. Additionally, OP question was attempting to solve the problem using `append` and recursion; this answer shows a way to do just that. More significantly, this answer has a critical typo, and Lisp style problems with parentheses and snake-case identifiers.

Comment: @user91628 -- there was a critical typo at the end of your function (`last` --> `lst`); I fixed the typo and improved the code formatting. A few style notes: prefer `kebab-case` to `snake_case` in lisps; don't spread closing parentheses over multiple lines (this isn't C); it is more idiomatic to use `cond` instead of nested `if`s.

Comment: I fixed the typo and the snake_case problem. Thanks!