# How to create tail recursive reverse list procedure?

Tags: function, recursion, scheme, reverse, tail-recursion

This is similar question to this one [How to Reverse a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092113/how-to-reverse-a-list) but for iterative (tail recursive) function. How can I create such function? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or even more explicit:

```
    (define (reverse xs)
     (let loop ((pend xs)
                (res '()))
       (if (null? pend)
           res
           (loop (cdr pend) (cons (car pend) res)))))
```

The *fold* answer by Chris is more neat and can be better wrt performance (for various reasons).
As of second part of your question it is always possible, i.e. every function can be made tail-recursive (e.g. by transforming to cps, which can be done mechanically).

Comment: Of course, a function that's really recursive and only becomes tail-recursive via CPS transformation doesn't really fulfil the "unbounded tail recursion doesn't result in unbounded memory consumption" requirement of proper tail recursion. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes; in fact the standard implementation of `reverse` is totally tail-recursive.

```
(define (reverse xs)
  (fold cons '() xs))
```

Don't like using `fold`? No problem:

```
(define (reverse xs)
  (do ((result '() (cons (car xs) result))
       (xs xs (cdr xs)))
      ((null? xs) result)))
```

Comment: just a short note, as not every scheme has fold built in, it's in srfi-1. obviously this is a left-fold.