# Is there a way to write your own recursive function to reverse a list in Scheme?

Tags: recursion, scheme

I am a little new to this side of things and was wondering what a recursive function to reverse a list would look like in Scheme. Any help is appreciated

I know there are built-in functions that are capable of reversing lists and I am familiar with those, but how would someone write their own?

Comment: It would look just like a recursive function that outputs a new list from your existing one in the same order, except that you would make your recursive call *first,* and then add the element to the list.  This will cause the elements to be added to the new list *as the stack unwinds, in reverse order.*

Comment: Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4092113).

Comment: Use a helper function that takes two arguments: the rest of the list that needs to be reversed, and an accumulator list to hold the reversed one. If the first list is null, return the accumulator. Otherwise, call itself with the cdr of the first list and that car consed onto the accumulator.